# WAXSIM automated testing and builds using Jenkins with xcodebuild

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, ios-simulator, jenkins

I am utilizing WAXSIM with JENKINS to create automatic tests after successful nightly builds.   As the build runs I watch both the remote system that is actually running Jenkins and the WAXSIM code to verify that the simulator is launched and then the see the application install into the simulator.  The problem is that after the install of the app on the simulator, the app immediately crashes immediately after it becomes active.  The icon remains on the simulator.  I confirmed, by launching XCODE on the Jenkins/WAXSIM remote system and installing (via xcode BUILD/RUN) the Testable.xcodeproj on the simulator.  It launches and runs just fine.  Same name too. I'm using Jenkins and the XCODE plugin to actually build and link the code and then I an "Execute Shell" step that actually checks for and kills the simulator as well as running waxsim.   All the tests run successfully when I use the build/run on the test target in XCODE at the desktop and on the remote system.

Also the message "Session failed to start. Simulator timed out." appears after about 15-30 seconds.

Here are the last lines from the jenkins build/test results:

```
test of Testable_(Integration_Tests)-Debug-1.0-dSYM.zip OK
[common_checkout] $ /bin/sh /var/folders/_w/4rf6zzws23j75lvcbgsnc_fm0000gx/T/hudson5038947848545058317.sh
About to build GUI tests scheme
About to run waxsim - a long delay here might suggest something is obstructing the view of the simulator on build slave
Testing finished
======== PRINT temp file to STDOUT ========

Launching '/Users/jenkins/.jenkins/common_checkout/ios/sandbox/dwallace/testable/trunk/testable/documentation/examples/testable/build/release-iphoneos/Testable (Integration Tests).app' on'Simulator - iOS 5.1'
Session failed to start. Simulator session timed out.

======== End PRINT temp file to STDOUT ====
===========================================
GUI Tests failed
===========================================
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Comment: How are you running Jenkins? As launch daemon? Does Jenkins need access to GUI session to run the GUI tests? Does it have such access? If you make a simple job that runs "screencapture test.png", does it work?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by removing all of the spaces from the application's target name as well as project.   Then it ran without issue.

Comment: are you sure that was the issue? btw you'll get xp if you mark your own answer as the answer